# Is the std::shared_ptr the same as adding "SharedPtr" to the name of a class when declaring a variable?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I encountered a somewhat odd "shared pointer" usage. As far as I know, shared pointers are written out as

```
std::shared_ptr<void()> pointy(fun, del);
```

However, I have a case where I have an interface *IGenericResult* (which all different result-classes implement). I found a place where it simply has "SharedPtr" added to the end of the name. Like this;

```
IGenericResultSharedPtr result = databasePointer->getLatestResult();
result->getTimestamp();   // Example of usage
```

It doesn't seem as if there is any defined class/interface/header/anything named *IGenericResultSharedPtr* so I can only assume it's something built into C++ (currently using version C++11 I think).

Is this the same thing as the *std::shared_ptr* (and if it is, how would I declare it in the *std* syntax)? If it's not the same thing, what differences are there?

Comment: This is most likely a `typedef` of something simelar. search for the declaration of `IGenericResultSharedPtr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "if the type name is `XYZSharedPtr`, it is instead `std::shared_ptr<XYZ>`" inbuilt into C++.

The authors of the code created a type alias somewhere, either

```
using IGenericResultSharedPtr = std::shared_ptr<IGenericResult>;
```

or

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<IGenericResult> IGenericResultSharedPtr;
```

(or possibly wrapped in a macro - who knows). Ask your IDE to find the definition :)

Comment: I tried searching for it. Found, in another file, two lines; "using DomainDataSpecPkg::IGenericResult;" and "using DomainDataSpecPkg::IGenericResultSharedPtr;" I also found a "luabind::class_<DomainDataSpecPkg::IGenericResult, boost::shared_ptr<DomainDataSpecPkg::IGenericResult>>("IGenericResultSharedPtr")" in another file. Really having a hard time understanding though. Have never worked with LUA stuff

Comment: PS: I don't really got an IDE. We're working with a common text editor and compiling through command line (and no, I do not like that very much)